# In the program called Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have such a demand, need to call in the program Google Maps software, if I use the following method call to map:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:" + restaurant.getLatitude() + "," + restaurant.getLongitude() + "?q=" + s));
startActivity(intent);
```

So that I can successfully call the Google Maps software, but if there are multiple maps when the system software, using the above approach will pop up for users to choose to display the map software, I now need to do is have more than one map even if the system software, But every time I call the Google Maps software to display. I ask how you can do, thanks! bythe way, Google Maps software is open source? In the android source code is not found maps related to the source code, where you can come?

I can successful invoke google map,but if android system have mutil map apps,system will propmt user to select which map app

Comment: Android is open-source, most of it's applications are not, so Maps the Application is not open-source.

Answer (score 2):

> But every time I call the Google Maps
>   software to display. I ask how you can
>   do

If you absolutely need Google Maps, add a `MapActivity` to your application.

> bythe way, Google Maps software is
>   open source?

No.

> I can successful invoke google map,but
>   if android system have mutil map
>   apps,system will propmt user to select
>   which map app

If the user installed a second map application, perhaps they want to use it. Please do not interfere.